# How to send messages to specific Discord channels using keywords?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Currently my bot will take any message that uses the !wts command and will mirror the message into a specified channel (which is set in the code).

How could I make it so if the message contained "UK8" it would be sent to the UK8 channel, or if it contained "UK3.5" it would be sent to the UK3.5 channel, so it would look for keywords and assign the message to the corresponding channel (rather than hard coding it like I have done).

I'm just getting started in Discord botting so I appreciate any help.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return undefined //bot does not reply to itself
  
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase()
    let args = message.content
      .slice(prefix.length)
      .trim()
      .split(' ') //arguments
    let command = args.shift().toLowerCase() //shifts args to lower case letters
  
    if (command === 'wts') {
      let say = args.join(' ') //space
      //message.delete() - remove // if you want to have each message deleted
      const generalChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('793494585123465875')
      generalChannel.send(message.author.toString() + ": " + say)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let nameChannel = "";

if(say.includes("uk8")){
    nameChannel = "UK8";
}else if(say.includes("uk3.5")){
    nameChannel = "uk3.5";
}else{
    nameChannel = "defaultChannel";
}

const selectedChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === nameChannel );
selectedChannel.send(say)
```